# YUI library to get contents of a website in a popup modal

Tags: javascript, popup, yui, popupwindow

Library : http://yuilibrary.com/

```
YUI().use('panel', function (Y) {

    var dialog = new Y.Panel({
        contentBox : //Need to get content from external website,
        bodyContent: '',
        width      : 410,
        height     : 500,
        zIndex     : 10,
        centered   : true,
        modal      : false,
        render     : '.example',
        visible    : true,
    });
});
```

In the content box, iframe do work, but is there any other way to render the website in a popup modal other than using iframe using YUI?

Comment: For sure, the requirement is to do it with YUI.. :)

Comment: What is wrong with using iframe?

Comment: Oh, nothing wrong. This is the first time I'm using it and checking is there a better way of using it other than iframe.

Comment: If you're displaying an external website, iframe will give you a "container" so that your styling and JavaScript don't "bleed" to / from the content in the iframe